# how to run jsp code on onclick

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want to update a column in my DB on the click of a hyperlink.

```
<%
while(rs.next()) {  
    name=rs.getString(1);
    url=rs.getString(2);
    desc=rs.getString(8);
%>
    <tr><td><a id="as" href="<%=url%>"><%=name%></a></td></tr>
    <tr><td><%=url%></td></tr>
    <tr><%=desc%></td></tr>    
<%
}
%>
```

Please guys help me sort out with this problem

Comment: What does the variables `url` and `name` translate to?

Comment: If the url is folder/abc.jsp then the browser will go to that file (and display it). if the url is folder/abc.jsp?id=1 then the file will be shown as well as passing the id value of 1. If you don't want the url file to be displayed then you will need to investigate using Ajax to update your db info.

Comment: use JSF to make interactive UI

Answer (score 0):

since ONCLICK is clientside and JSP is serverside, you can only **call** the JSP-Resource (which contains your JSP-CODE) via Javascript (or regular link).
On Client-Side, there is NO JSP-Code.

Comment: so is there any alternative solution to my problem(firing jsp code on click of mouse) and moreover,the second problem i'm facing is that when i var a=document.getElementbyId("as") it returns only the first element

Comment: consider using **JQuery** when dealing with elements, it makes life much easier. to your first problem, you can call a JSP-File or Servlet   to invoke Java-Code.But NOTE, this code will be executed on server-side. You can try do solve your problem by using AJAX.